# How do I switch an 18V LED circuit on/off with the signal from my amp to my speakers?

Tags: led, audio, switches

I have an LED strip in my Peavey 6505+ guitar amp and would like it to only illuminate when I play my guitar. I could get 4 LEDs to light up well by just wiring them in to a 1/4" jack from the output of my amp. It worked great. It did not have enough power to supply the entire 30 LED strip. They worked, but were very dim. I now have the LEDs wired to a spare 18V output from my power source, and am wondering if there is a switch that will activate the powered LEDs with the output from my amp. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [Darlington transistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darlington_transistor) or [Sziklai pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sziklai_pair) will let you use the weak signal from the amp to switch the LEDs on and off.

Comment: I got my hands on a TIP120 and can not figure out how to wire it in. I've tried many combinations. the closest I came still had the dim LEDs from when I wired it to the speaker by them selves. What am I doing wrong? Here is what I've got.[URL=http://s862.photobucket.com/user/KillKillWireWire/media/TIP120.png.html][IMG]http://i862.photobucket.com/albums/ab187/KillKillWireWire/TIP120.png[/IMG][/URL]

Comment: Create a new question including the schematic.

Comment: Need at least 10 reputation to post pictures. I guess I've got a bad reputation.

Comment: Post the link and someone will edit the image in.